# How to make part of string text clickable?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How can I display dialog box when part of a String.xml text is clicked? I have a long string and I want to make part of the string to display a dialog box when it is clicked.

Now, I don't want the text to take me to a link; but it should appear like a link. Then, it should take me to a dialog box activity when the text is clicked. The text shouldn't appear like a button also. It should look like a link text but it should display a dialog box when clicked.Moreso, the dialog box contain series of String to display more information about the text that was clicked.

**This is my String.xml**

> Upon the new birth, the believer is expected to grow (1 Pet. 2:2).This growth comes through the knowledge of our Lord and Saviour,Jesus Christ (2 Pet. 3:18) who is the essence, substance and testimony of the Scriptures (Jn. 5:39, Luk. 24:25-27, 44-47). We hope to teach the person of Jesus who is the word of God (Jn 1:1-17) and in so doing, find out what he has done for us, who we are in Him and what we have in Him. We also seek to find out truths about God by looking into Jesus who reveals God to us (Heb. 1:1-3, 2 Cor.4:3-4, Col. 1:12-15). In addition, the believer is expected to give glory to God in his conduct (1 Cor. 10:31), he is to be responsible and to walk in the reality of who he is. He is to be given to the service of God (Rom. 12:11). We pray that you receive the wisdom and revelation of the Spirit and that you increase in knowledge and understanding as we diligently study this manual together.
>   Blessings!

I want to click on the (1 Pet. 2:2) to display a dialog box that contains information the bible reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
public void makeLinks(TextView textView, String[] links, ClickableSpan[] clickableSpans) {
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
        for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan = clickableSpans[i];
            String link = links[i];

            int startIndexOfLink = textView.getText().toString().indexOf(link);
            spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + link.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
```

in onCreate() method

```
 ClickableSpan yourstringClick = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              openyourdialoghere()
            }
        };

        makeLinks(tvLink, new String[]{"your string"}, new ClickableSpan[]{
                yourstringClick
        });
```

**Edit**

For multiple strings

```
ClickableSpan yourstringClick2 = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  openyourdialoghere()
                }
            };

            makeLinks(tvLink, new String[]{"your string","your string 2"}, new ClickableSpan[]{
                    yourstringClick,yourStringClick2
            });
```

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
  I'm getting this error, what can be wrong?

Comment: tvLink is the textView in which you are displaying your string

Comment: thanks! it looks like a link now; but when I click on it. The link is not bringing up a dialog box..

Comment: can you show me what you have done for dialog box to appear

Comment: I used the code you sent, that is all. Please, can you help me out

Comment: in my code the function "openyourdialoghere()" is a user defined function in which you will create your dialog which you want to show.

Comment: Okay, but How will I include the string I want to display in the "openyourdialoghere()" function.  Show me an example please. I have zero idea on this

Comment: Please, help me out on this with an example.

Comment: you want to keep that string as title of your dialog box

Comment: Please refer this for creating alert dialog 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_alert_dialoges.htm

Comment: Yeah, I want to keep that string as the title

Comment: set "yourstring" as title of you dialog as given in the link

Comment: Thanks so much! I will get back to you. I'll read up the link also.

Comment: Your answer were helpful and the link also. But what if I want to add more than one string as link. Will I introduce a else if statement? or what am I going to do?

Comment: i have edited the answer. Please try. If doesn't works then will give you another solution.

Comment: 's Thank you so much. I will try that.

Comment: Is it possible to link the string link to a database ?.. Such that when the link is clicked, popup that appears will be from a database? I asked this cause I have multiple Strings that I want to make as a link....... So, the dialog box message and dialog box title will be extracted from the database....